# my LAN pcs are not able to connect to the Internet. I am using DHCP server and linkys router

Tags: router, dhcp, hosts

My connection details:
A have atotal 10 PCs connected to Linksys router. DHCP is enabled in the router.

> IP adddress: 192.168.0.103---013
>       subnet 255.255.255.0
>       gateway: 192.168.0.1
>       DNS server 10.0.0.2

When I ping to default gateway its pinging successfully.

But I can not connect to any Internet websites.

What is the problem? If more info is required then I can provide that.

Comment: Can you ping a computer based on its IP? (Or rather, can your DHCP client reach the DNS server?)

Comment: yes i can ping my pc ip address and default gateway. 127.0.0.1 is also ok.

Comment: Well, 127.0.0.1 would be ok. It is localhost and will work even without network cable. But can you ping a computer outside the LAN on its IP? E.g. `ping 8.8.8.8`. If that works then you have a working Internet connection and probably a resolver problem.

Comment: You mention the default gateway is 127.0.0.1 (localhost loopback) in your comment but your original post shows 192.168.0.1. Can you clarify that the actual defualt gateway is? Seems odd that DNS server would be 10.0.0.2 but without more info, that may remain a mystery. Can you provide the results of ipconfig /all and post into origianl answer? Ping an external site like google.com or by IP for a known address like 8.8.4.4 (Google DNS) Also try rebooting the router and modem if you have not done so recently.

Comment: Is there another network between your router and modem? If not, it seems unlikely 10.0.0.2 is providing DNS, given you're using the range 192.168.0.0/24. Try a different IP in the DNS server field, e.g. 8.8.8.8.

Comment: resolver problem means --DNS problem? i called ISP. they are replying that their network is ok from thier end to demarc area. trace route is also not sucessful. still now i did not ping 8.

Comment: where did you get that DNS from? How is your router connected to the internet (cable modem?)?

Answer (score 1):

Unless you are running your own DNS server on the same LAN, and you gave that DNS server an address of 10.0.0.2... your problem is definitely due (in part at least) to the fact that you are using 10.0.0.2 as your DNS server address.  Why?  10.x.x.x is a private internal IP address and reserved for LAN usage only.  It is not an address that would be used by any publicly accessible DNS.

As recommended in the comments, if you change your DNS server address to 8.8.8.8 (Google's public DNS) or 208.67.222.222 (openDNS address) you should have no problem accessing the internet.  Your best bet would be to put one (or both) of these addresses in your router on the DNS settings page, rather than setting them manually on any of the computers.